# How to upload text from android app to my RDS database through my EC2 server

Tags: php, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i want to call my EC2 server and it run a script (PHP?) so i can insert/delete data to/from my RDS database then pull data out of the database and display it on my android app.

So i connected my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server to my RDS MySQL database because i downloaded phpMyAdmin on the server and i can take the IP from the server (from the AWS dashboard) put it like this "34.4.94.34/phpmyadmin" in the brower phpMyAdmin shows up and i can sign in and access my database.

I downloaded a WAMP server on my laptop (before i messed with AWS) and i set up my code to look at a PHP script and it'll register my account (basically take the two strings from my code and store it into my localhost database). So i uploaded the same PHP files into my server and changed my code so itll call the the PHP from my server and send the data to the RDS mySQL database.

my question is: i am i doing anything wrong? & How can i can i get my android app to talk to my server and the server update my database?

Any code/links will be helpful! also i am kinda new to all this so please be specific! thank you!!

original Android code that would  save the data to my local WAMP database:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String,Void,String> {
Context ctx;

public static boolean LOGIN_FAILED = true;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Make sure the IP address is correct.
    String register_URL = "http://192.168.0.13/WilsApp/register.php";//Holds the location of my php file.
    String login_URL = "http://192.168.0.13/WilsApp/login.php";

    String method = params[0];

    if(method.equals("register")){//If the method in BuyerFillOutForm is equal to "register" then it'll do the try block.
        String BuyerFirstName = params[1];
        String Password = params[2];

        try {//Try block is to see if the call to the database can work.
            URL url = new URL(register_URL);//Create a new URL and put there variable "register_URL" into it.
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();//Create a httpConnection and open it
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");//Use the request method
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("BuyerFirstName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(BuyerFirstName, "UTF-8") + "&"
                       + URLEncoder.encode("Password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Password, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();

            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();

            return "Registration is a success!";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { //url.openConnection() catch statement
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    else if (method.equals("login")){
        String Email = params[1];
        String Password = params[2];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_URL);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");//Use the request method
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("Email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("Password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Password, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            String response = "";
            String line = "";

            while((line =  bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                response += line;
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //if(result.equals("Login failed...")){
    //    LOGIN_FAILED = true;
    //}else{
    //    LOGIN_FAILED = false;
    //}

    if (SignInForm.WIFI_ON_OR_OFF == true) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Makes a toast showing the user that the registration worked.
    }
}
}
```

init.php:

```
<?php

//Creates a connection to the database

$db_name = "BuyerAccounts";
$mysql_user = "phpmyadmin";
$mysql_pass = "phpmyadmin";
$server_name = "54.175.14.82";

$connection = @mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass,      $db_name);

if(!$connection){
//echo "Connectionn Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{
//echo"<h3>Database connection Success...</h3>";
}

?>
```

register.php:

```
<?php
require "init.php"; //Calls the file to make a connection to the database.

$user_name = $_POST["BuyerFirstName"];
$user_pass = $_POST["Password"];

$sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$user_name', '$user_pass');";                 //Inserts the two variables into the database.

if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query)){
//echo"<h3> Data insertion success...</h3>"; //If we connect to the database         and the query works then it displays the echo.
}
else{
//echo"Data insertion error...".mysqli_error($connection); //Else the     defualt echo is displayed with the method that says why.
//echo"no connection"
}

?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$user_name = $_POST["Email"];
$user_pass = $_POST["Password"];

$sql_query = "select user_name from user_info where user_name like     '$user_name' and user_pass like '$user_pass';";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row["user_name"];
echo "Welcome ".$name."";

}else{
echo "Login failed...";
} 
?>
```

Comment: You are making an HTTP POST request from Android to the PHP web server, and then the web server is performing an update to the MySQL database. So far that sounds correct. Have you ran this code? Does it all work? Are there any problems? Are any error messages printed? You don't actually list any problems in your question. I suggest you read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: my apologizes with the question, but i cant figure out how to call my PHP file on m AWS EC2 server

Comment: Get the public IP or DNS name of your EC2 instance and use that. You should be able to test the URL in your web browser and figure out what the correct URL is, then put that URL in your Android app. It looks like you are currently using the private EC2 IP address, which won't work. There are of course other issues like your web server may not be running, or your security group may not be open, etc.

Comment: Given the extra information you added in your duplicate question, the obvious answer to this question is to replace the values "192.168.0.13" in your two URL strings with the actual IP address of your server, "12.09.23.39". Although it appears your server is down right now and will probably have a different IP when you start it back up unless you are using an Elastic IP.

Comment: if i try this "http://54.175.14.82/WilsAppPHP/login.PHP" in chrome it comes back as a 404 error "The requested URL /WilsAppPHP/login.PHP was not found on this server." 

on android i get this error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://54.175.14.82/WilsAppPHP/register.PHP"

i know my server is up because it says running on AWS and i can connect to the phpMyAdmin on it.

also my security group on the server has MS SQL, HTTP, All TCP, and SSH all open.

i don't know whats wrong :(

Comment: Your server may be running but those PHP files aren't installed on your web server correctly. Once you install them correctly, probably by moving them to the correct location under `/var/www` maybe, then the URLs will work. If you need help installing those PHP files ask that as another question.

Comment: They aren't under that directory so that might be the problem. I'll test this once I get home from school. I'll keep you posted once I test it out. Thanks for all the help Mark!